# Silex redirect changing the locale

Tags: php, redirect, locale, silex

I am using Silex 2 and I would like to redirect to homepage with default locale if any url is loaded using an invalid locale.

```
    // homepage / root
    $this->get('{_locale}/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('index/index.html.twig', array());
    })->bind('homepage');
```

Before middleware:

```
    // i18n Control
    $locale = $request->getLocale();
    $allowLocale = ['en','es','de'];
    if (!in_array($locale, $allowLocale)) {
        $request->setLocale('en');
        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($app['url_generator']->generate('homepage'), 301);
        $response->prepare($request);
        return $response->send();
    }
```

But this code produces an infinite loop.

I want:

If user insert this URL: /es/foo then all is ok.

If user insert this URL: /fr/foo then he must be redirect to /en.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same, but easily as you can pass the URL parameter to the url_generator service. Also to make your app more flexible and less error prone, you should embarace the container for global configurations (for *allowedLocales* and *defaultLanguage*):

```
// somewhere in your configuration
$app['defaultLanguage'] = 'en';
$app['allowedLocales'] = ['en','es','de']

// Then in your controller
$locale = $request->getLocale();
if (!in_array($locale, $app['allowLocales'])) {

    $request->setLocale($app['defaultLanguage']);
    $app['translator']->setLocale($app['defaultLanguage']);

    return $app->redirect(
        $app['url_generator']->generate('homepage', ["locale" => $app['defaultLanguage']]), 
        301
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution:

```
    $locale = $request->getLocale();
    $allowLocale = ['en','es','de'];
    if (!in_array($locale, $allowLocale)) {
        $defaultLanguage = 'en';
        $targetUrl = $app['url_generator']->generate('homepage');

        $request->setLocale($defaultLanguage);
        $app['translator']->setLocale($defaultLanguage);

        $targetUrl = str_replace("/$locale/", "/$defaultLanguage/", $targetUrl);

        return $app->redirect($targetUrl, 301);
    }
```

But I would like to implement other solution more elegant.

What do you think guys?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, it has been useful to me.